# Routing Error - Switching Index File in Rails - Bootstrap Theme Implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-sass

I am trying to implement a bootstrap theme in my rails app I just created.

First I created new project with Rails new scaffold, and created a database. the Index page worked fine, showing a table of the database content. (I am using this tutorial to go through it:https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1)

However, as I try to implement the bootstrap theme, I am running into an issue. I read from another tutorial to manually copy and paste the contents of the bootstrap theme over to my apps corresponding folders. My goal is to copy the bootstrap's template index.html file over, so that I can start from there.

I am trying to replace the default index.html.erb file with the index.html file that came with my bootstrap theme. So I copy the file, rename it to match the original file. Then remove the original index html file. But when I do this my routing won't work. I get the routing error listed below.

What do I do? If I put the old index file pack in the views it works again. But when I try to switch it stops working.

I get this error when trying to load the page:

Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/index"

Rails.root: /Users/../code/lettersTest3

Comment: Has the file name and location remained the same?

Comment: How us more information on how you are trying to switch the files: Usually you simply change the HTML and CSS inside your existing *index.html.erb* to match the themes HTML, but not switch the files.

Comment: @leito I am switching files by renaming the template index file, to the same index.html.erb file name. Then removing the old index file. Thinking that it would work because it has the same filename. Should I just copy the code into the original index html file?

Comment: @leito if I wanted to switch the files. What do you have to write to let the app know you have switched the index?

Comment: @mmichael - I took the template that was given with my bootstrap, changed the name to index.html.erb thinking that it would just route to that instead. But doesn't seem to be working. What is the code within the original index.html.erb file that tells the ruby app to route to it??

Comment: Please show us all that on your question, we are trying to help but we are not looking at your screen. Be explicit about it in your question and start small, make 1 thing work and move from there.

Comment: @leito - thanks for your feedback. I have updated the question to be more specific. Let me know if I am missing something or if I can be more specific in certain areas and I will be more than happy to post more info :)

Comment: That's a much better better question/description, run rake routes on your terminal to return a list of valid routes. Usually, instead of /index, / (alone, without the index) does the trick, but it truly depends on the content of your routes.rb. So both could work with the right setup.

Comment: @Leito - My routes.rb simple has:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :letters
  root 'letters#index'

Comment: rake route gives me:
    letters GET    /letters(.:format)          letters#index
            POST   /letters(.:format)          letters#create
 new_letter GET    /letters/new(.:format)      letters#new
edit_letter GET    /letters/:id/edit(.:format) letters#edit
     letter GET    /letters/:id(.:format)      letters#show
            PATCH  /letters/:id(.:format)      letters#update
            PUT    /letters/:id(.:format)      letters#update
            DELETE /letters/:id(.:format)      letters#destroy
       root GET    /                           letters#index

Comment: Ok so I just changed the file name to 'theme.html.erb' then made that the root. And routed it in the routes.rb file and that seems to have made it the homepage.  so its a fix for now :)